# GWT Celltable server side pagination

Tags: java, gwt, pagination, server-side

How to make a server side pagination ( like AsyncDataProvider for sort column);? 
I can override SimplePager behavior:

```
 SimplePager pager = new SimplePager() {

        @Override
        public void nextPage() {
            //AsyncCallToServer
            super.nextPage();
        }

        @Override
        public void previousPage() {
            //AsyncCallToServer
            super.previousPage();
        }
    };
```

But, I think there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, AsyncDataProvider allow for grid pagination